# Why does ropevim throw a TypeError?

Tags: python, vim, rope

Whenever I use any function in RopeVim, Vim shows me the following error at the end of the stack trace:

```
Type error: Got inexpected keyword argument 'verbose'
```

And I really have got no clue whatsoever on what is causing it.

Comment: I found the answer. It was actually that I had to also install ropemode and ropevim.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [ropevim](http://rope.sourceforge.net/ropevim.html) website:

> You should install rope and ropemode before using ropevim.

You can get ropemode from [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ropemode).